# Operations on a smooth vector bundle

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

On a smooth vector bundle, one often defines addition and scalar multiplication to form a vector space. However, doesn't one need to show that these operations are smooth? Is this trivial or is there an easy way to do it on a smooth vector bundle?

Comment: Do you mean addition and scalar multiplication of sections?

Comment: Well given the usual vector bundle mapping from some topological space $E \to M$ we define the usual addition as a mapping $E \oplus E \to E$ and scalar multiplication as a mapping $\mathbb{R} \times E \to E$

Comment: Hmm it probably follows from taking a local trivialization about each point and using the axioms of the vector bundle.

Comment: I tried that before, but didn't really get anywhere.